# Edit SQL records through php

Tags: php

I am trying to edit records within an sql table using a php script. I am able to load up a form that will let me edit the text but it wont save the new record name when I press submit. It just redirects me to the table page with no edits.

(DB included)

```
<?php

function renderForm($ArtistName = '', $error = '', $ArtistID = '')
{
    // ...
}

if (isset($_GET['ArtistID'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (is_numeric($_GET['ArtistID'])) {
            $ArtistID = $_GET['ArtistID'];
            $ArtistName = htmlentities($_POST['ArtistName'], ENT_QUOTES);
            if ($ArtistName == '') {
                $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
                renderForm($ArtistName, $error, $ArtistID);
            } else {
                if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE Artists SET ArtistName = ? WHERE ArtistID=?")) {
                    $stmt->bind_param("s", $ArtistName);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();
                } else {
                    echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're missing a `bind_param` for the `ArtistID`, right?

Comment: Ive just added it in thanks @Syscall but still no fix

Comment: if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE Artists SET ArtistName = ?
WHERE ArtistID=?"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("si", $ArtistName, $ArtistID);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

Comment: Why there's an `s` in `bind_param("s",...`?! Actually, it should be `bind_param(1,$ArtistName);` and the second one `bind_param(2,$ArtistID, PDO::PARAM_INT);`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) says:

> Parameter identifier. For a prepared statement using named placeholders, this will be a parameter name of the form `:name`. For a prepared statement using question mark placeholders, this will be the 1-indexed position of the parameter.

In your code, you're using `"s"` as a parameter for `bindParam`!

```
<?php
function renderForm($ArtistName = '', $error = '', $ArtistID = '')
{
    //
}


if (isset($_GET['submit'])){
    if (isset($_POST['ArtistID'])){
        if (is_numeric($_GET['ArtistID'])){
            $ArtistID = $_GET['ArtistID'];
            $ArtistName = htmlentities($_POST['ArtistName'], ENT_QUOTES);
            if ($ArtistName == ''){
                $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
                renderForm($ArtistName, $error, $ArtistID);
            }else{
                if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE Artists SET ArtistName = ? WHERE ArtistID=?")){
                    $stmt->bind_param(1, $ArtistName);
                    $stmt->bind_param(2, $ArtistID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();
                }else{
                    echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```